# How to POST data to JSS Route

Tags: jss, sitecore-react

I am using Sitecore JSS in integrated mode. I have below scenario and need help to achieve it.

When user will login to the web site, he can be part of one or more groups. After login user will see the data of his default group. User can see the data of his other groups by changing the group name from dropdown list. I can achieve this by passing group id and other required parameters in query string. However customer don't want to pass these in query string.

Please let me know how I can pass (post) data to route or page. Or what is the best way to achieve it?

I am using Sitecore 9.1 update 1 with React Js in integrated mode.

Thanks,
Alok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. If the groups data is represented by items in Sitecore, you can utilize the GraphQL endpoint. It is provided OOB within JSS and supports all types of GraphQL request as well as POST request. You can read how to use it by the link: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/graphql-overview
2. If the groups data is some third part data, you can implement a custom API controller and handle POST request from frontend there.